# How to stop youtube video when click on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I've been googling for a while but i didnt get any good results for my problem. I also ready many times the youtube api reference from gdocs.

Im trying to stop a youtube video by clicking on a link.

html:

```
<div class="box_filme rel_trailer">
    <iframe id="iframe_player" width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8Af372EQLck?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

script src:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

js code im trying:

```
$(function(){
   $('.info_filme .filme').click(function(){
        $('iframe_player').stopVideo();
   });
});
```

part of the html that the clicks are placed

```
<ul class="info_filme">
    <li><a class="filme sinopse active" data-info="rel_sinopse">Sinopse</a></li>
    <li><a class="filme trailer" data-info="rel_trailer">Trailer</a></li>
    <li><a class="site" href="">Site</a></li>
</ul>
```

In fact I had success calling the url link from js but i have to use iframe and i don't know what im doing wrong.
If someone could help me i'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `.stopVideo()` on a jQuery object, not on a YouTube player object. The YouTube API does not export its control functions to the iframe element, and certainly not to jQuery.

Rather than creating the iframe yourself, try letting the YouTube API do it for you, as in the [basic example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) in the YouTube iframe API docs.

```
    var player = new YT.Player($('.rel_trailer')[0], {
      height: '315',
      width: '420',
      videoId: '8Af372EQLck',
      events: {
        'onReady': function() {
            $('.info_filme .filme').click(function(){
                player.stopVideo();
            });
        },
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
```

The first parameter that gets passed to `YT.Player` is the DOM element in which you want YouTube to put the video.

The YouTube API gets a bit tricky, since a lot of what it does is asynchronous. If you want something a whole lot easier, Popcorn.js can wrap a YouTube player in an API that mimics a HTML video element (as I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516345/howto-play-youtube-videos-via-html5-video-tag/13544295#13544295)).

You need to load up these scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="popcorn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popcorn._MediaElementProto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement.js"></script>
```

You can get them [here](https://github.com/hapyak/popcorn-js/blob/feature/youtube/popcorn.js), [here](https://github.com/hapyak/popcorn-js/blob/feature/youtube/wrappers/common/popcorn._MediaElementProto.js) and [here](https://github.com/hapyak/popcorn-js/blob/feature/youtube/wrappers/youtube/popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement.js). (This repo is a few bug fixes ahead of the official Popcorn repo for YouTube.)

Next, just provide an empty element for the video.

```
<div class="box_filme rel_trailer"></div>
```

Now, create the wrapper and attach the click handler.

```
var video = Popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement($('.rel_trailer')[0]);
video.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Af372EQLck';

$('.info_filme .filme').click(function(){
    video.pause();
});
```

Popcorn will handle loading YouTube's API and all the asynchronous events that follow. It's a fair amount of unnecessary javascript to load if you're not going to use Popcorn's main annotation functions, but it'll save you a lot of time if you don't want to be bothered mucking about with YouTube's API. And you'll be able to easily adapt the code if you want to have vides from multiple sources (e.g. HTML5, Vimeo).

Comment: By the way, your jQuery selector for 'iframe_player' is incorrect. It should be '#iframe_player' to match the element's id.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you embed the video into your page like below?

```
<embed id="playerid" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" name="playerid" style="" src="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayerbeta?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=normalplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

You can then stop the video using:

```
var myPlayer = document.getElementById('playerid');

<a href="#" onclick="myPlayer.stopVideo();">Stop Video</a>
```

Comment: im trying to use this embed tag but it doesnt seen to work. it only shows a black square without any player options or video.

take a look:
<embed id="playerid" width="420" height="315" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" name="playerid" style="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8Af372EQLck?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=normalplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
what am i doint wrong?

i also tried use src without the '../embed/..'