# how to make an universal HTML5 video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I need to build a universal html5 video player that **play's videos with web links**, for example: http://youtu.be/o_1aF54DO60 or http://example.pt/video/aadygx.

I've tried this, but dosen't work:

```
<video width='500' heigth='500' controls='controls'>
  <source src='http://youtu.be/o_1aF54DO60'>
</video>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j29nA/

How can i do this for all kinds of web links given by the user?

Comment: Try `src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/o_1aF54DO60'`. Your URL doesn't actually point to a file.

Comment: i've tried, didn't worked

Comment: The youtube link you're using directs to a **page that includes the video** and not a direct link to the video file itself. Finding that direct link is somewhat tricky. YouTube won't let you embed their videos in whatever player you want, obviously.

Comment: have a look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516345/howto-play-youtube-videos-via-html5-video-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to test if the link comes from youtube or vimeo and parse the given URL to an embebed URL in order to use their `<iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

```
    <video>
<source src="MP4-VIDEO-URL" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
<source src="WEBM-VIDEO-URL" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
<source src="OGV-VIDEO-URL" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>

<object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
data="FLASHPLAYER-URL"> 
<param name="movie" value="FLASHPLAYER-URL" /> 
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "MP4-VIDEO-URL", "autoPlay":false, "autoBuffering":true}}' /> 
</object>
</video>
```

More info can be found from
http://www.doomby.com/pages/webmaster-tutorials/pages/add-universal-video-support-with-html5.html

or

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html#fbid=pgr3yUv00os