# embedding you tube video in html5 video tag

Tags: youtube, html5-video

i want to embed you tube video in to HTML page by using html5 video tag.
what i have done is

```
<video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ejjOfl_HRhc" />
</video>
```

but this code doesn't produce any result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto Play YouTube videos via HTML5 video tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516345/howto-play-youtube-videos-via-html5-video-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. Use a MIME type supported by the browser (`video/youtube` is not a registered MIME type at all).
2. Provide a URL to a video (`http://www.youtube.com/embed/ejjOfl_HRhc` is an HTML document).

YouTube probably don't want you hotlinking their video files and likely take steps to prevent it. You should use their official embedding code or host the videos yourself instead.